# Browser shows Server Error in '/' Application MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Currently I  am Working with `MVC4`.I have doubt, I tried to debug when `index.cshtml` is open ,
It shows `Server Error in '/' Application`.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: `HTTP 404.` The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

```
Requested URL: /Views/Report/Index.cshtml

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929.
```

When I debug with other pages than `index.cshtml`, it works fine.Why it happens? Can you please give resolution?

Comment: Check routing and View name

Comment: Check you have a index.cshtml in the Views/

Answer (score 2):

I think you are requesting wrong URL: /Views/Report/Index.cshtml

It should be ***hostname/Report/Index*** i.e. `http://localhost/Report/Index`

Answer (score 2):

You are calling it wrong way..

Your request pattern should be as follows:

`ControllerName/ActionName`

Therefore your request sholud be `http://localhost/Report/Index`

The process is as follows:

1. When you will hit `http://localhost/Report/Index`
2. your request will get redirected to `Index Action` located in `ReportController.cs`
3. Then the `Index Action` will return the `Index.cshtml` `view` located in `"Views/Report"` folder.